# How to send Token with POST request to Django REST api from Android App?

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST framework TokenAuthentication. I am able to recieve token from api when i sends username and password. But how to send that token with every request from android app to the server?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the Token in your shared preferences so you can access it everywhere in your app: so you dont have to give it with the intent everytime

> final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
>                       "PACKAGE NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

you can put the Token in it by

> prefs.edit().putString("Token",tokenvalue).apply();

and retrieve it by

> prefs.getString("Token","DEFAULT VALUE");

You can send the Token with your request by putting it in the Headers:

> HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
>           httpPost.setHeader("authorization",prefs.getString("Token","DEFAULT VALUE");

Comment: Your answer is useful. Everything is fine but problem is HttpPost is deprecated

Comment: URLConnection replaced all the apache classes HttpClient etc.

Comment: Can you provide me the code in context of URLConnection?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/362398/Servlets/java/setting-http-Header-urlconnection
I think that will do the trick

Comment: also can you tell me how to add header in AsyncHttpClient(loopj) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the token in the header you send with the request, where the random string is your token:

```
Authorization: Token 1af538baa9045a84c0e889f672baf83ff24
```

Comment: i am able to use that if i make a request from a client. I tested this using requestmaker.com. But in android can you tell me how to set header?

Comment: apache library and its functions has been deprecated from api 22

Comment: do we have alternate for that?
AsyncHttpClient by loopj is available but i don't how to add header in that...Can you help me out?